# Генератор для поиска путей в дереве

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия, дерево, итераторы

Есть генератор. Он должен быть рекурсивным. Идея подобна LR-обходу дерева (обход всех потомков слева направо). В явном виде дерева здесь нет, но оно неявно создаётся в процессе разворачивания рекурсии:

```
def solve_generator(k, s, res):
    if s == 0:
        yield res
    if k >= 0 and s - x[k - 1] >= 0:
        res.append(x[k - 1])
        solve_generator(k - 1, s - x[k - 1], res)
        res = res[:-1]
    if k >= 0:
        solve_generator(k - 1, s, res)
```

Иными словами, это перебор с отсечениями. В рамках этого генератора происходит мы заглубление по стеку. Приведу пример вызова генератора:

```
x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 20, 25]

s = 22

g = solve_generator(len(x), s, [])
for k in g:
    print(k)
```

**Моя проблема**: мне бы зотелось на строке, на которой указан `yield` произвести выход из стека рекурсии наружу (без итерации по стеку наверх), а при повторном вызове вернуться в то же место стека для продолжения построения решения. Вопрос: возможно ли это в питоне или требуется избавиться от рекурсии?

Для того, чтобы понять, что делает эта программа, Вам следует знать постановку задачи. Она звучит так:

По заданному числу `s` и массиву `x`, следует построить все возможные решения для задачи о разложении числа `s` на слагаемые. Я делаю это итеративно и эксплуатирую идею [задачи о рюкзаке](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5).

В более простом варианте, данная задача может быть поставлена так: как написать рекурсивный генератор, который будет step-by-step возвращать пути в дереве?

Comment: добавьте массив `x`, чтобы пример был полным

Comment: Добавил @EugeneDennis

Comment: `yield` и так вернет найденное решение без возврата по стеку вызовов. При следующей итерации генератор продолжит работу с того же места, и будет выведено следующее решение.

Comment: @insolor приведите пример. Пусть даже не срекурсией. А с любой подобной рекурсивной функцией.

Comment: @insolor Он работает не верно, так как `solve_generator` только создаст генератор но не вызывет его. В конкретном примере, не будет выведено ничего. А это, разумеется, неверно. Это произойдёт из-за того, что программа, сделав один вызов функции `solve_generator`, установит, что условие `k >= 0` верное, дойдёт до последнего условия, создаст генератор, а затем выйдет, не сделав вызов онного.

Comment: Ок, понял, посмотрю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для рекурсивного вызова генератора можно использовать `yield from` (Python 3.3 и выше) - тогда все решения, найденные в глубине рекурсивных вызовов будут переданы выше по уровню. Подсмотрено здесь: [Can generators be recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254304/can-generators-be-recursive)

Слегка изменил алгоритм, чтобы в коде было меньше `k - 1`, добавил вывод суммы для контроля.

```
def solve_generator(k, s, res):
    if s == 0:
        yield res
    if k >= 0:
        if s - x[k] >= 0:
            yield from solve_generator(k - 1, s - x[k], res + [x[k]])

        yield from solve_generator(k - 1, s, res)

x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 20, 25]

s = 22

g = solve_generator(len(x)-1, s, [])
for k in g:
    print(k, sum(k))
```

Вывод:

```
[20, 2] 22
[20, 2] 22
[20, 2] 22
[20, 2] 22
[20, 2] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 7, 1] 22
[14, 5, 3] 22
[14, 5, 3] 22
[14, 5, 3] 22
[14, 5, 3] 22
[14, 5, 2, 1] 22
[14, 5, 2, 1] 22
[14, 3, 2, 2, 1] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 7, 3] 22
[12, 7, 3] 22
[12, 7, 3] 22
[12, 7, 3] 22
[12, 7, 2, 1] 22
[12, 7, 2, 1] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 2, 2, 1] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 3, 2, 2] 22
[8, 7, 3, 2, 2] 22
```

Чтобы выводило меньше дублей, можно изменить алгоритм так:

```
def solve_generator(k, s, res):
    if s == 0:
        yield res
    if k >= 0:
        if s == x[k]:
            yield res + [x[k]]

        if s - x[k] > 0:
            yield from solve_generator(k - 1, s - x[k], res + [x[k]])

        yield from solve_generator(k - 1, s, res)

x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14, 20, 25]

s = 22

g = solve_generator(len(x)-1, s, [])
for k in g:
    print(k, sum(k))
```

Тогда останутся только дубли из-за повторяющихся двоек:

```
[20, 2] 22
[20, 2] 22
[14, 8] 22
[14, 7, 1] 22
[14, 5, 3] 22
[14, 5, 2, 1] 22
[14, 5, 2, 1] 22
[14, 3, 2, 2, 1] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 8, 2] 22
[12, 7, 3] 22
[12, 7, 2, 1] 22
[12, 7, 2, 1] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 3, 2] 22
[12, 5, 2, 2, 1] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 5, 2] 22
[8, 7, 3, 2, 2] 22
```

## Как работает `yield from`?

`yield from` возвращает из генератора все, что возвращает другой генератор (или тот же самый, как в нашем случае). По сути работает как такой цикл:

```
# yield from solve_generator(k - 1, s - x[k], res + [x[k]]) эквивалентно
for item in solve_generator(k - 1, s - x[k], res + [x[k]]):
    yield item
```

Comment: Поясните, как работает `from`. Насколько я понял, это не совсем то, что нужно. Я пробовал его использовать. Но не до конца разобрался

Comment: Дополнил ответ.